# MongoDB analysis with Saiku Community Edition

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, saiku, apache-calcite

I am unable to connect Saiku with MongoDB using optiq even.I already copied Jars into saiku lib and web-inf lib. As saiku add data Source console doesn't have any Catalog field and also the url part too.

Comment: I am facing same problem before but didn't succeeded, for more [check this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/optiq-dev/AWdejwLvqPA/sonUdc4qBkgJ) may it will help you

Comment: Ya i checked that google groups but can't succeed.Thanks for your info @yogesh

Comment: Yogesh, can u pls share your OptiqMongo.xml